# Unable to slice an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array, slice

I'm trying to get data from non-contiguous rows. The columns are fixed but the row numbers vary. The result I'm expecting is a 2-D array. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but the slicing using index function is not working.

```
'Just for example to get the data from row number 100, 500 and 900 and the columns from A to F
arr = Application.Index(Sheet2.Range("A:F"), array(100, 500, 900))
```

I thought if 3rd parameter is left blank row slicing will be done. But the resultant array is single dimensional (size 3) and is populated with Error 2023.

So I gave another try by giving 3rd parameter too.

```
arr = Application.Index(Sheet2.Range("A:F"), array(100, 500, 900), array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

Even now the resultant array is single dimensional (size 6) but first three indices have data and the rest have Error 2042. Is it possible at all to get a 2-D array by slicing a 2-D array? If yes, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row array needs to be vertical:

```
arr = Application.Index(Sheet2.Range("A:F"), Application.Transpose(Array(100, 500, 900)), Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

[image]

One can always create a 1D array of numbers from 1 to the number of columns and use that:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheet2.Range("A:F")

Dim test As Variant
ReDim test(rng.Columns.Count - 1)

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(test) To UBound(test)
    test(i) = i + 1
Next i

Dim arr As Variant
arr = Application.Index(rng, Application.Transpose(Array(100, 500, 900)), test)
```

Comment: Nice. That worked well. But is the third parameter required always? I mean I want data from all the columns. In the example I've given A:F but what if my range spans across several columns like AE:DE. Is it possible to shorten the 3rd parameter?

Comment: @saikrishna no but you could fill a 1d variant array with the numbers in a loop then use that.

Answer (score 1):

### Slice Array Rows

- Note that for contiguous columns you can e.g. use:

  ```
  [Row(1:1)] ' first column
  [Row(1:3)] ' first three columns
  [Row(2:5)] ' four columns after the first
  [Row(3:4)] ' two columns after the second
  ```
- If you need the flexibility of also choosing non-contiguous columns, then instead of `[Row(1:6)]` you could e.g. use:

  ```
  Application.Transpose([{1,3,4,6}])
  Application.Transpose(Array(1, 3, 4, 6))
  ```

**A Quick Fix**

- Returns three rows by six columns from a 2D one-based array in a 2D one-based array.

```vb
Sub QuickFix()
    ' Don't use entire columns, it takes too long.
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns("A:F")
    'Debug.Print rg.Address(0, 0)
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(rg.Value, [{100,500,900}], [Row(1:6)]))
    ' Three rows, six columns ('H1:M3')
    Sheet2.Range("H1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
End Sub
```

**A Study**

```vb
Sub Random()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    
    ' A Row (1D one-based: one row, three columns)
    arr = [{3,5,7}]
    Debug.Print "Row (Random)"
    Debug.Print LBound(arr), UBound(arr)
    
    ' A Column (2D one-based: three rows, one column)
    arr = Application.Transpose([{3,5,7}])
    Debug.Print "Column (Random)"
    Debug.Print LBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 1), LBound(arr, 2), UBound(arr, 2)

End Sub

Sub Sequence()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    
    ' A Row (1D one-based: one row, six columns)
    arr = Application.Transpose([(Row(1:6))])
    Debug.Print "Column (Sequence)"
    Debug.Print LBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 1)

    ' A Column (2D one-based: six rows, one column)
    arr = [Row(1:6)]
    Debug.Print "Row (Sequence)"
    Debug.Print LBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr), LBound(arr, 2), UBound(arr, 2)

End Sub

Sub TwoD()
    
    ' Source Array (2D one-based: ten rows, six columns)
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = Range("A1:F10")
    Debug.Print "Source"
    Debug.Print LBound(sData, 1), UBound(sData, 1), LBound(sData, 2), UBound(sData, 2)
    
    ' Transposed Array (2D one-based: six rows, three columns)
    Dim tData As Variant
    tData = Application.Index(sData, [{3,5,7}], [Row(1:6)])
    Debug.Print "Transposed (Wrong)"
    Debug.Print LBound(tData, 1), UBound(tData, 1), LBound(tData, 2), UBound(tData, 2)
    
    ' Destination Array (2D one-based: three row, six columns)
    Dim dData As Variant
    dData = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(sData, [{3,5,7}], [Row(1:6)]))
    Debug.Print "Destination (Correct)"
    Debug.Print LBound(dData, 1), UBound(dData, 1), LBound(dData, 2), UBound(dData, 2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a very detailed answer. I wish I could accept multiple solutions as answers.